# How to vertically center images in a CToolbar after changing the height of CToolbar at runtime

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a Visual C++ MDI application. In this app, I have 3 toolbars of type CToolBar. To respond to runtime DPI changes (such as the user changing the display settings on the screen on which the app is displayed), I resize the height and sometimes the width of the toolbars. The toolbar resizing works fine, except for one issue. **When I change the height of the toolbar, the toolbar button images do not vertically center. Instead, the toolbar button images maintain their position relative to the top edge of the toolbar. This doesn't look nice.** Important to point out that I am loading the images from a file at runtime. If I close the app and restart it, the images are then correctly positioned within the toolbar.

My algorithm for this toolbar runtime sizing is as follows:

- user changes DPI at runtime
- based on new DPI, determine needed height for toolbar
- detach existing bitmap from toolbar that is used for toolbar button images
- delete each toolbar button
- reset the size (height) of the toolbar based on the new DPI setting
- attach the bitmap of images to the toolbar so the buttons will have images

Using the above alorithm, i would expect to see the newly loaded toolbar images vertically centered within the toolbar. However, the images are not vertically centered. Instead, they are closer to the top edge of the toolbar than the bottom edge of the toolbar. It is as if the images decided to keep their top left coordinate consistent despite the increase in toolbar height. This issue happens even if I intentionally load the same size images as were used prior to the runtime DPI change.

Here is the code for the algorithm detailed above:

```
//in my CMainFrame.h file (where CMainFrame is a CMDIFrameWnd)
CToolBar my_toolbar;
CBitmap m_bitmap_for_toolbar;

//in my CMainFrame.cpp file  (where CMainFrame is a CMDIFrameWnd):

//detach the existing bitmap used for the toolbar images
(HBITMAP)m_bitmap_for_toolbar.Detach();

//remove the existing buttons prior to resizing the toolbar
int iButtonCount = my_toolbar.SendMessage(TB_BUTTONCOUNT, (WPARAM)0, (LPARAM)0);
for (int i = iButtonCount; i > 0; i--)
{
    nButtonIndex = i - 1;
    my_toolbar.SendMessage(TB_DELETEBUTTON, (WPARAM)nButtonIndex, (LPARAM)0);
}

//assign new size for the toolbar
my_toolbar.SetSizes(CSize(new_button_width, new_button_height), CSize(button_image_width, (button_image_height));

//create new buttons for the toolbar
TBBUTTON tbButtonsFile[3] =
{
    { 0, ID_FILE_NEW,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)NULL},
    { 1, ID_FILE_OPEN,  TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)NULL},
    { 2, ID_FILE_SAVE, TBSTATE_ENABLED, BTNS_AUTOSIZE, {0}, 0, (INT_PTR)NULL}           
};

my_toolbar.SendMessage(TB_BUTTONSTRUCTSIZE, (WPARAM)sizeof(TBBUTTON), 0);
my_toolbar.SendMessage(TB_ADDBUTTONS, (WPARAM)3, (LPARAM)&tbButtonsFile);
my_toolbar.SendMessage(TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);
my_toolbar.Invalidate();

//load images from a file for the toolbar buttons
HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage(NULL, str_bitmap_file_path, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE);
m_bitmap_for_toolbar.Attach(hBitmap);   //attach bitmap that will be used for toolbar images
my_toolbar.SetBitmap(m_bmpToolBarFile);     
my_toolbar.Invalidate();

//set the toolbar styles
my_toolbar.SetBarStyle(my_toolbar.GetBarStyle() | CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC);
```

Comment: Personally, I scale the images in the toolbar to fit the buttons as they resize.  This seems to work OK.

Comment: I've had to do this. Just like MFC, I have a set of bitmaps at 16 and 24(not sure, just know I do it.). And just select the bitmaps accordingly. Works well though not perfect. I might add a 32 if resolution goes to or beyond beyond 200%. Then there is no runtime StretchBlt, it stays your image.